# Use a literal value to refer to constant in Golang

Tags: go, constants

I have defined a constant with a type. I want to use the value of a variable to refer to the constant. (Please refer to the code below).
One way would be to define a map of Key to the required Value. Is there another approach to do this ?

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Code int

const (
    MY_CONST_KEY Code = 123
)

func main() {
    x := "MY_CONST_KEY"
    //Fetch Value of x as 123
}
```

Comment: fmt.Println(x) would give me output as "MY_CONST_KEY", what I need to print is "123"

My intention is x can be anything during runtime, i need to map x to the list of constants and get the corresponding value

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do what you are asking. You cannot pass constants to the reflect package without instead passing their literal value.

As you correctly mentioned, you can use a map:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Code int

var codes = map[string]Code{
    "MY_CONST_KEY":      123,
    "ANOTHER_CONST_KEY": 456,
}

func main() {
    x := codes["MY_CONST_KEY"]
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

If you make sure the map is not exported (lower case `c` in `codes`), then it will only be available inside your package, so consumers of your package cannot modify the map at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning x to a string, "MY_CONST_KEY", you can do x :=  MY_CONST_KEY

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Code int

const (
    MY_CONST_KEY Code = 123
)

func main() {
    x := MY_CONST_KEY
    fmt.Println(x) // This fetch the value of x as 123
}
```

Comment: `x` is something which would be generated on runtime so it can be any value.

Answer (score -1):

> One way would be to define a map of Key to the required Value.

Yes, do that.

> Is there another approach to do this ?

No.